# SpringBatch with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-batch

Hi folks need some opinions here.
I already have a spring boot application holding all my rest APIs running on tomcat that ships in with spring-boot-starter-web.

I would like to set up jobs using spring batch that will be schedule via kubernetes. The idea is to share the same business logic instead of creating a standalone batch project which i need to maintain double business logic.

Question, scheduling via kubernetes meaning i will be firing java -jar someJar --spring.batch.jobNames=xxx in container, doing that it will also start up all my RestApis right? which in turn unnecessary and waste of resources. Anyway to mitigate this or my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would implement this is by extracting the common business logic in a separate module, and make the batch app and the webapp depend on that module.